# How to change the port number of a NetTcpBinding ServiceEndpoint that is registered with a ServiceHost

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I am trying to modify the port-number on which my self-hosted WCF service listens. For this I tried stopping the ServiceHost, adding a new ServiceEndpoint with the new port and then restarting the ServiceHost. However this does not work and it throws this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Endpoints cannot be added after the ServiceHost has been opened/faulted/aborted/closed.

Here is my test code:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task IsRunning_ForServerRunning_IsTrue()
    {
        server.Close();
        var newPortNumber = 6767;
        server.Open(newPortNumber);
        Assert.True(server.IsRunning);
    }
```

and this is `AutomationServer`:

```
public class AutomationServer : IAutomationServer
{
    private ServiceHost svh;
    private IAutomationService service;

    public AutomationServer(IAutomationService service)
    {
        svh = new ServiceHost(service);
    }

    public void Open(int port = 0)
    {
        Open(port, null);
    }

    public void Open(int port, string host)
    {
        //if (port != 0)
        this.port = port;

        if (host == null)
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName;
        var baseUri = new Uri("net.tcp://" + host + ":" + this.port);
        Open(baseUri);
    }

    public void Open(Uri baseUriAddress)
    {
        var serviceEndpoint = svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(IAutomationService),
        new NetTcpBinding(),
        baseUriAddress);

        if (baseUriAddress.Port == 0)
            AutoAssignPortNumber(ref serviceEndpoint);

        svh.Open();
        IsRunning = true;
    }

    private void AutoAssignPortNumber(ref ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
    {
        serviceEndpoint.ListenUriMode = ListenUriMode.Unique;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        svh.Close();
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    ... properties, etc.
}
```

So is the correct way to just "discard" the old ServiceHost and create a new ServiceHost with the new binding in the ServiceEndpoint or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I ended up just creating another ServiceHost instances with the new ServiceEndpoint set to the desired port. No idea if that's ideal, but it works.